# Black screen: MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi after installing mesa git

Tags: xorg, 19.10

Black screen, then glitch, then again black screen.

```
MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi
```

Last thing I did was installing libdrm 2.4.100. But uninstalling it didn't help. The thing I don't plan uninstalling are `youtube-dl` and `python3`.
I think it's related to it loading it from `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri`

Comment: so the black screen then glitch is probably your display manager triyng to start X, X failing to start, so the display manager tries again. What is in `/var/log/Xorg.log`?
Have you tried reinstalling mesa? As that should pull in any missing dependencies.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge or experience with `libdrm`, but when you installed it was anything removed? (esp. if you used `-y`)  If you don't remember, look in you [/var/log/apt/] history   *where I'd look first, ie. clues in what you did that caused it*

Comment: @guiverc it was from source with `meson` and `ninja`, that's reversable install as far as i know.

Comment: @Minijack there is one line about power button being removed at one point, mouse being detected as keyboard, printer and some other garbage which it isn't. It's PixArt in the logs.

Comment: @guiverc also i haven't tried to reinstall mesa because i don't think there are any trouble with it EXCEPT i tried installing latest git.

Comment: @Minijack no errors in the log

Comment: It seems to be caused by mesa git installed in /usr/local/

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by mesa git I installed recently, it was fixed by

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Not sure if it's a proper way but it worked.